# Reuse LEDs from a LED bulb

Tags: led

I am planning to build a high luminosity lamp to act as a growth lamp during winter for my plants.

For this, I manage to recycle (upcycle?) a big LED bulb with the following inscription:

```
LED Corn Light E40
Volt: AC 35-265V
CC1: 6000K
Power: 54W
```

The bulb was not matching my needs as is (especially since it was providing an almost 360 degree light, while I need a directional light source), so I took it apart.

I saved 8 nice aluminium strips with 19 SMD LEDs each. I plan to power these from an ATX power supply, so I have a 12V 15A (probably I should say something like 10-12A to be safe) source.

The problem is that I can't identify these LEDs (I couldn't find a datasheet), so I'm not sure how much power they need. Based on similar LEDs I've seen around, I think 3V and 250 mA per LED would be a good guesstimate. Which means I should form groups of 4 LEDs in series and add a 3/0.25 = 12 ohm resistor per pair, everything nicely stuck to a solid piece of aluminum for cooling.

Are my calculations correct?

Side question: I was measuring the LEDs with a diode meter and it seems they very dimly light up. Also, when touching them in certain conditions, they produce a very dim light (the LEDs being disconnected from any circuitry). Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: *"I was measuring the LEDs with a diode meter and it seems they very dimly light up"* That's normal... The meter needs to use voltage and current to determine a resistance so it is partially powering the LED.

Answer (score 5):

If the whole lamp is rated at 54W, and it contains 8 strips of 19 = 152 LEDs, then the power per LED it's been designed for is 54/152 = 355mW before losses.

If you run each LED at 3V 250mA, that's 750mW, more than twice what is was designed for.

Comment: 100 mA is probably closer to the correct value.

Comment: In the absence of knowledge of the original device's rating, how would you recommend going about determining a reasonable drive current? (I'm just curious, but I think this would potentially improve the answer as well.) Would there be any method better than "slowly turn up the current until they look 'bright enough'"?